# Browse the internet from the command line

Tags: shell, command-line, browser, web, lynx

I know there are command-line web browsers like `w3m` `lynx` etc. But I am looking for a simpler tool to just print search queries. Somewhat like `curl` does, but more nicely formatted.

Like if I run `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=linux`

I would get something like:

```
Top 3 Best Desktop Linux Distros | 2019 Edition
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZ7nI2im4Yg
_________________________________________________
The Next Ubuntu? - Clear Linux First Impressions
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuCxCLFDfwM
_________________________________________________
The Next Ubuntu? - Clear Linux First Impressions
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUGd99GRAfo
_________________________________________________
```

in simpler words just Title and Link

---

**EDIT:** with thanks to the comments I did some further research on *web-scraping* and found [this code](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/using-linux-shell-web-scraping/) using `wget` and two applications from the `html-xml-utils` package in combination with `lynx`:

```
   link="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=linux"

   wget "$link" -O- |
   hxnormalize -x |
   hxselect -i "div." |  #in this line I'm missing the proper pattern
   lynx -stdin -dump
```

if I inspect the title displayed in a youtube.com search I get:

```
<div id="title-wrapper" class="style-scope ytd-video-renderer">
  <h3 class="title-and-badge style-scope ytd-video-renderer">
    <ytd-badge-supported-renderer class="style-scope ytd-video-renderer" disable-upgrade="" hidden="">

    <dom-repeat id="repeat" as="badge" class="style-scope ytd-badge-supported-renderer" style="display: none;"><template></template></dom-repeat>
    </ytd-badge-supported-renderer>
    <a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" title="What is Linux?" href="/watch?v=zA3vmx0GaO8" aria-l$
                What is Linux?
    </a>
  </h3>
<div id="menu" class="style-scope ytd-video-renderer"></div>
</div>
```

I do not get what pattern to use in `hxselect` in order to grep the title and link.

Comment: Sounds like you want to [extract all external links of a web page](https://superuser.com/questions/372155/how-do-i-extract-all-the-external-links-of-a-web-page-and-save-them-to-a-file).

Comment: There's no general way to do this that automatically leads to "nicely formatted output", you have to analyze the web page on a case-by-case basis. This is also known as "web scraping". There are command line tools like `sgrep` that can assist in parsing the web page.

Comment: I can also suggest `python` in combination with `beautifulsoup` for web scraping.